# Trouble recognizing time and distance values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am parsing data from a remote server, which returns XML data. In the response data there are two attributes `time` and `distance`. Both of these have weird values such as `time=48.435` and `distance=16415.195`. I am parsing this XML data using jQuery. Now I really don't know what sort of time and distance values these are.

Could you please tell me what kind of values these are, and how I can convert them into minutes for time and meters for distance using jQuery?

**Note: I am adding jQuery and Javascript tags, because I am using jQuery to parse XML.**

**update**

Here is how the output looks like in the API response:

[image: Here]

Comment: What is the remote server?  Do you have a link to an API?

Comment: There should be some specification in your API. I doubt anyone can interpret the units for these values if they are missing.

Comment: The specs for this api does not mention anything about these time formats. I almost completed the app for this api now I am having trouble with these formats. :(

Comment: When I load that URL, the responses are in this format: <ARRIVAL date="20121118" time="0958"/>, and the documentation states that the times are in HHMM format.  What function are you using to parse it?

Comment: @Alex no. Check it in LENGTH tag please

Comment: @Alex I am already following documentation for this api but could not find any help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that part of the response.  Do you have a link to the API docs as well?

Comment: @Alex yes here is the link to the api docs http://developer.reittiopas.fi/pages/en/http-get-interface.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you linked to tells you what you need:

> 1.8.1.2 LENGTH element
>
> This element gives the time in minutes and distance travelled in the
>   distance units of the request of a route, leg or walk.

i.e. time is in minutes, distance in the units as defined in your request.

However, I did not find how to specify the distance units in the request.

Can you just try with a few samples for which you know what the result should be?